# Generating unique names in textfield

Tags: tables

I am wrinting a LaTeX document and I'd like it to be editable in Acrobat. I'm using Textfield provided by eforms.

This document is a longtable with a description and two cells the user needs to fill with text. I have about 300 lines and I can't imagine I need to create a name for each texffield I have (line * number of cells).

If I let the name empty, or if the name is the same for 2 textfields, then Acrobat Reader bugs so I wanted to concatenate eg rownumber and columnumber but I don't know how to retrieve the last one.

Is there any way to do it ?

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}


\begin{document}
  \section{}

  \begin{longtable}{|p{12cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
    \hline 
    \sc text here & \sc form1 & \sc form2 \\
    \hline
    \endhead

     text here & \TextField[{maxlen=2,align=0,borderwidth=1,height=8pt,width=1cm,name=}]{} & \TextField[{maxlen=2,align=0,borderwidth=1,height=8pt,width=1cm,name=}]{} \\
    \hline

   \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Please check if this helps. Here the roman numerals are used to name the fields
(not actually checked for 300 lines).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}

\makeatletter
\newcount\fldn@me\fldn@me=1
%
\def\TextFieldX{%
\xdef\textFldName{name=\romannumeral\fldn@me}
\expandafter\TextField\expandafter[\expandafter{\textFldName,maxlen=2,align=0,borderwidth=1,height=8pt,width=1cm}]{}%
\global\advance\fldn@me1
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{Section A}
  \begin{longtable}{|p{12cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
    \hline 
    \sc text here & \sc form1 & \sc form2 \\
    \hline
    \endhead
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
    \hline
   \end{longtable}

  \section{Section B}
  \begin{longtable}{|p{12cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
    \hline 
    \sc text here & \sc form1 & \sc form2 \\
    \hline
    \endhead
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
      text here & \TextFieldX  & \TextFieldX \\
    \hline
   \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course this helps ! I wouldn't have thought about roman numeral. Very smart ! It really does the trick, thanks.