# Find height of each row in longtable

Tags: hyperref, longtable

I am enumerating through a list e.g. `list = ["some text", "some other text"]` to dynamically create a table with two columns. The first column is text taken from the list, and the second column is a fillable `TextField` using the `hyperref` package.

The text in the first column can differ in length, changing the height of the row accordingly.  I'd like to be able to set the height of the `TextField` in the second column to fill up the entire height of the row.

Is there anyway to access the row height of the first column so I can place that inside of the `TextField` parameters, i.e. `Textfield[width=\linewidth, height=\rowheight]`.

[image]

My code below. Note I'm using LaTeX via Jinja2 so it might not be very helpful. I'm also using the solution suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139553/generating-unique-names-in-textfield) to generate unique names for each of the `TextFields`.

```
%This creates a repeatable TextFieldX component
\makeatletter
\newcount\fldn@me\fldn@me=1
%
\def\TextFieldX{%
\xdef\textFldName{name=\romannumeral\fldn@me}
\expandafter\TextField\expandafter[\expandafter{\textFldName, borderwidth=0, backgroundcolor={.85 .85 .85}, rotation=90, multiline=true, align=0, height=\rowheight}]{}%
\global\advance\fldn@me1
}
\makeatother

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{ p{0.45\textwidth} p{0.45\linewidth} }
    \hline
    \textbf{Text} & \textbf{Fillable textfield} 
    \hline
    \BLOCK{ for i in list}
    %recommendation
    \text{list[i]} 
    &
    %action
    \TextFieldX
    \\
    \BLOCK{ endfor }
    \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}
\pagebreak
```

Comment: note `\begin{center}  \begin{longtable}{ m{0.5\textwidth} m{0.5\linewidth} }` looks wrong `center` does not center a longtable (it just adds vertical space) and you have to two columns of width .5\textwidth but \tabcolsep padding on either side of each column so it will be 4\tabcolsep (24pt by default) too wide on every line.

Comment: you haven't provided a usable test document but basically you want to so something like `\savebox\mybox{\parbox{\hzize}{  your text}}` in the first column then you can use the `\ht\mybox` and `\dp\mybox`  to set the bounds of the text box on that row.

Comment: Instead of `p{0.45\textwidth}` use `l` and `\sbox0{\parbox[b]{0.45\textwidth}{...}\usebox0` and the height is given by `\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0'`